# Why isn't word allowing me to make page 2?

Tags: windows, microsoft-word-2013

I have a document with text boxes, its an inspection report. I would like to add a blank page to add some details. When completed the document will be printed to both sides.

However, it is not giving me the option to insert a new page. I tried to copy and paste the document into a new word file, but it doesn't even keep the formatting as it was originally.

The current page is filled right to the bottom. Hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> to try and bring up a page only creates more tables on the new page. Deleting the tables deletes the whole page.

Why isn't word allowing me to make page 2?

Comment: Are you certain the cursor is at the bottom of the page?

Comment: When your cursor is inside a table you are limited in what you can enter. So make sure your cursor is outside the table and then try adding lines.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. I cleaned up your question to make it easier to read and remove your rant about Word as it was subjective. If you feel I have changed too much, feel free to roll it back or edit it yourself. We can help you resolve the page issue, but could not possibly know why, in our opinion, Word is useless.

Comment: My other question is this; you state the document has "*text boxes*" and then you state "*creates more tables*" and "*deleting tables*". Can you clarify? Do you have both tables and text boxes? Or are you using table cells as textboxes?

Answer (score 0):

Click the very last line in the table, and then press the down arrow key. The cursor should now be outside (after) the table. Press Ctrl-Enter to insert a new page.

If somehow you were still in the table when you pressed Ctrl-Enter, a new table would be created on the next page. You can delete this table without deleting the page.